# php output not the same after being put in a function

Tags: php, guzzle, domparser

I'm trying to make a php script that scrapes the price of competitor products from their website, I managed to have a somewhat functioning script with a json output, but when I wanted to make the urls of the competitors a variable being inputted by the user, it all went sideways.

I know I must have messed up somewhere, this is actually my very first php script.

Here's the "first version" (the one that works) :

```
<?php
require 'C:\Users\dgayg\vendor\autoload.php';

use \GuzzleHttp\Client;
use \PHPHtmlParser\Dom;
use \CurrencyDetector\Detector;


$productPairs = [
    'ASICS FUJITRABUCO LYTE' => [
        'RunnerInn' => [
            'url' => 'https://www.runnerinn.com/magasin-running/asics-chaussures-de-femme-asics-fujitrabuco-lyte/138541586/p',
            'selectorPath' => '#total_dinamic'
        ],
        'iRun' => [
            'url' => 'https://www.i-run.fr/chaussures_homme/Trail_c15/Asics_m1/Asics-FujiTrabuco-Lyte-M_Asics_fiche_92311.html',
            'selectorPath' => '.price'
        ],
        'Zalando' => [
            'url' => 'https://www.zalando.fr/asics-gel-trabuco-terra-chaussures-de-running-deep-sea-tealblazing-coral-as141a0r6-k11.html',
            'selectorPath' => 'span.uqkIZw.ka2E9k.uMhVZi.dgII7d._6yVObe._88STHx.cMfkVL'
        ]
    ]
];

$detector = new Detector();

$comparison = [];

foreach ($productPairs as $productName => $pair) {


    foreach($pair as $provider => $product) {

        $client = new Client();
        $parser = new Dom;

        $request = $client->request('GET', $product['url']);
        $response = (string) $request->getBody();
        $parser->loadStr($response);
        $price = $parser->find($product['selectorPath'])[0];
        $priceString = $price->text;

        $fmt = new NumberFormatter( 'fr_FR', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY );

        $comparison[$productName][$provider] = [
            'Prix' => $detector->getAmount($priceString)." ".$detector->getCurrency($priceString)
        ];     

    }
}

echo json_encode($comparison);
```

Its output is the following : `{"ASICS FUJITRABUCO LYTE":{"RunnerInn":{"Prix":"120.26 EUR"},"iRun":{"Prix":"94 EUR"},"Zalando":{"Prix":"76.95 EUR"}}}`

And now here's the version where I put my code in a function and tried to make the user input the URLs :

```
<?php

require 'C:\Users\dgayg\vendor\autoload.php';

use \GuzzleHttp\Client;
use \PHPHtmlParser\Dom;
use \CurrencyDetector\Detector;



function comparateur($site1, $site2) {
    return 
        $productPairs = [
            'ASICS FUJITRABUCO LYTE' => [
                'iRun' => [
                    'url' => $site1,
                    'selectorPath' => '.price'
                ],
                'Zalando' => [
                    'url' => $site2,
                    'selectorPath' => 'span.uqkIZw.ka2E9k.uMhVZi.dgII7d._6yVObe._88STHx.cMfkVL'
                ]
            ]
        ];
            $detector = new Detector();

        $comparison = [];

        foreach ($productPairs as $productName => $pair) {


            foreach($pair as $provider => $product) {

                $client = new Client();
                $parser = new Dom;

                $request = $client->request('GET', $product['url']);
                $response = (string) $request->getBody();
                $parser->loadStr($response);
                $price = $parser->find($product['selectorPath'])[0];
                $priceString = $price->text;

                $fmt = new NumberFormatter( 'fr_FR', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY );

                $comparison[$productName][$provider] = [
                    'Prix' => $detector->getAmount($priceString)." ".$detector->getCurrency($priceString)
            ];

            }
        }
    echo json_encode($comparison);

}

// echo comparateur(($_POST['site1']), ($_POST['site2']));

if (isset($_POST['site1']) && isset($_POST['site2'])) {
    $result = comparateur($_POST['site1'], $_POST['site2']);
}
?>
<html>
<body>
    <!-- <p>https://www.i-run.fr/chaussures_homme/Trail_c15/Asics_m1/Asics-FujiTrabuco-Lyte-M_Asics_fiche_92311.html</p>
    <p>https://www.zalando.fr/asics-gel-trabuco-terra-chaussures-de-running-deep-sea-tealblazing-coral-as141a0r6-k11.html</p> -->
    <form action="" method="post">
    <p>iRun: <input type="text" name="site1" value="https://www.i-run.fr/chaussures_homme/Trail_c15/Asics_m1/Asics-FujiTrabuco-Lyte-M_Asics_fiche_92311.html" /></p>
    <p>Zalando: <input type="text" name="site2" value="https://www.zalando.fr/asics-gel-trabuco-terra-chaussures-de-running-deep-sea-tealblazing-coral-as141a0r6-k11.html" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit"/></p>
    <?php if (isset($result)) { ?>
        <h1> Result: <?php print_r($result);?></h1>
    <?php } ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Its output is the following : `Result: Array ( [ASICS FUJITRABUCO LYTE] => Array ( [iRun] => Array ( [url] => https://www.i-run.fr/chaussures_homme/Trail_c15/Asics_m1/Asics-FujiTrabuco-Lyte-M_Asics_fiche_92311.html [selectorPath] => .price ) [Zalando] => Array ( [url] => https://www.zalando.fr/asics-gel-trabuco-terra-chaussures-de-running-deep-sea-tealblazing-coral-as141a0r6-k11.html [selectorPath] => span.uqkIZw.ka2E9k.uMhVZi.dgII7d._6yVObe._88STHx.cMfkVL ) ) )`

Can someone please tell me where I messed up, because I really cannot figure it out.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Try this, change the echo inside function to return.

```
<?php

function comparateur($site1, $site2) {
    return 
        $productPairs = [
            'ASICS FUJITRABUCO LYTE' => [
                'iRun' => [
                    'url' => $site1,
                    'selectorPath' => '.price'
                ],
                'Zalando' => [
                    'url' => $site2,
                    'selectorPath' => 'span.uqkIZw.ka2E9k.uMhVZi.dgII7d._6yVObe._88STHx.cMfkVL'
                ]
            ]
        ];
            $detector = new Detector();

        $comparison = [];

        foreach ($productPairs as $productName => $pair) {


            foreach($pair as $provider => $product) {

                $client = new Client();
                $parser = new Dom;

                $request = $client->request('GET', $product['url']);
                $response = (string) $request->getBody();
                $parser->loadStr($response);
                $price = $parser->find($product['selectorPath'])[0];
                $priceString = $price->text;

                $fmt = new NumberFormatter( 'fr_FR', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY );

                $comparison[$productName][$provider] = [
                    'Prix' => $detector->getAmount($priceString)." ".$detector->getCurrency($priceString)
            ];

            }
        }
    return json_encode($comparison); // CHANGE echo to return
}

// echo comparateur(($_POST['site1']), ($_POST['site2']));

if (isset($_POST['site1']) && isset($_POST['site2'])) {
    $result = comparateur($_POST['site1'], $_POST['site2']);
    echo $result;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer, I have just tried it, but it did not work, do you have any other ideas about where I possibly would have messed up?

Comment: Now it worked ! my bad I forgot to remove the first return, thanks a lot !